# Node How to use routes in parallel function

Tags: node.js, express

i am trying to make node render more faster.

then i want use parallel.

so how to put in routes in parallel function?

**before**

```
var app = express();
var index = require('./routes/index')();
var auth = require('./routes/auth')();

app.use('/',index);
app.use('/auth/',auth);
```

**after ( I am trying this)**

```
var app = express();
var index = require('./routes/index')();
var auth = require('./routes/auth')();

function parallel(middlewares){
   return function (req, res, next){
      async.each(middlewares,function(mw,cb){
        mw(req,res,cb);
      },next);
    };
  };

app.use(parallel([
    ['/',index],
    ['/auth/',auth],
    [others here]
]));
```

Comment: What is the problem with your 2nd code block that you want help with?  Do you realize that node.js runs all your Javascript single threaded so there is no true parallel execution.  But, if your middleware uses asynchronous operations, then you can improve responsiveness by running multiple middlewares at the same time where they will be interleaved when one is waiting for an async response, the other can run and vice versa as long as you don't care what order they run in.  Personally, I'd probably use Promises and `Promise.all()` to know when they're all done instead of `async` here.

Comment: Hmmm, I see a problem with your current scheme.  There is path routing because you aren't passing any path to `app.use()` so all middleware will execute for all requests, yet you have paths specified for some.  Your scheme could work only if all middleware were specified with the same path.  To supports separate paths for parallel middleware where only the middlewares that matched the path on that particular request were launched in parallel would be hard.  You'd somehow have to get Express to tell you which middlewares should be run for this route before any have actually been run.

Comment: It also troubles me to see an `auth` middleware in your parallel list.  That is usually `required` to run in a particular order before other requests run as a means of verifying or implementing authentication.

Comment: Did you just disappear?  I spent a LOT of time on an interesting, but complicated problem and I think I came up with a usable solution for parallelizing middleware, but you seem to have just disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this.  It comes with a few caveats which are mostly due to the fact that Express is designed around sequential middleware, but by following a set of guidelines you can make it work just fine.

**The Problem Statement**

1. We want to pass in a group of middleware and have them run in parallel (or as parallel as their async operations will allow).  If you have multiple independent async things to do in middleware, this should be able to get to an end result quicker (which is pretty much the whole point of doing this).
2. We want to be able to pass in typical routing paths (with all wildcards and special characters) as in `app.use('/product/:id', fn)` and then execute only the routes that match the current request "in parallel" with each other
3. We want Express itself to do all the route matching so we don't have to reimplement or copy any of that and so that everything Express normally supports for route matching is supported.
4. We want to support route parameters like `req.params`, even though those may be different for each middleware (not quite so common to use this in middleware, but still part of the Express design).

**The Design Scheme**

We create our own Router object.  To that router object, we add a "start" marker middleware at the beginning (so we can see when routes are starting on this router), then we add a place holder middleware with the proper path for each of our parallel middleware handlers and then we add another "end" marker middleware at the end (so we can see when routes are done on this router).  The "start" and "end" routes match all routes so they are always called.  The other routes have the path that was passed in for them so they may or may not get called for any given request depending upon whether they match the current path or not.

This router gets added to the routing stack with `app.use(router)`.  In this way, the regular Express engine will do all the routing for this router and decide which routes match the current request path.  But, rather than execute the regualar middleware functions when it finds a matching route path, it will just execute our placeholder middleware.  When it executes the placeholder middleware, we will get to see the "start" middleware, any other middleware that matches the route which we will capture in a list and then the "end" middleware.  When we get the "end" middleware, we will have captured the list of middlewares that match the current route and we can then go execute just those actual middlewares in parallel.  When all those middlewares are done, we then call `next()` for our router allowing the rest of routing to continue.

So, in summary, we insert dummy route handlers with the actual route paths and let Express call our dummy route handlers if the path matches as a means of telling us which routes match the current path.  Then, we take that list of matching routes and set them up for parallel execution.  In this way, Express does all the work of telling us which routes match the current request path.

**Implementation**

So, to implement this, I define a new `app.useParallel()` and we add a fourth parameter to the middleware function for `req.param` that belongs to that specific middleware route definition.

```
// pass an array of path, fn pairs
// ['/', func1, '/somePath', func2]
app.useParallel = function(array) {
    // create a router that will be inserted only for route matching
    let router = express.Router();

    // insert route at beginning to make start of routes getting called
    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        req.routeList = [];
        next();
    });

    // let the router have dummy route handlers with all the right paths
    // so we can use it to see which paths it will match
    for (let r of array) {
        router.use(r[0], function(req, res, next) {
            // for each route that actually gets called (and thus must have matched the path),
            //   save the corresponding callback function and a copy of the req.params
            req.routeList.push({fn: r[1], params: Object.assign({}, req.params)});
            next();
        });
    }

    // now insert route at end of router that matches all routes to know when we're done
    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        let routeList = req.routeList;
        if (routeList && routeList.length) {
            // now we are ready here to execute the route handlers in req.routeList in parallel
            let len = routeList.length;
            let doneCnt = 0;
            let nextCalled = false;
            for (let middleware of routeList) {
                middleware.fn(req, res, function(err) {
                    ++doneCnt;
                    if (err) {
                        // make sure we only call next() once
                        if (!nextCalled) {
                            nextCalled = true;
                            next(err);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (doneCnt === len && !nextCalled) {
                            next();
                        }
                    }
                }, middleware.params);
            }
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });

    // insert this router in the chain
    app.use(router);
}
```

And, then this is used like this:

```
function test1(req, res, next, params) {
    // some async operation that calls next() when done
    next();
}

// similar definitions for test2(), test3() and test4()

app.parallel([['/', test1], ['/', test2], ['/:id', test3], ['/test', test4]]);
```

---

**Restrictions**

Running multiple middlewares potentially in parallel leads to some restrictions on the middleware - all of which seem somewhat expected if you're setting up for parallel operation.  Here are some of the restrictions:

1. You will get interleaved execution of these handlers if any handler uses asynchronous calls and then completes sometime later.  Since node.js is still single threaded, this will NOT do parallel execution of purely synchronous middleware handlers.  If they are synchronous, they will still be executed synchronously.
2. The initial synchronous part of each parallel middleware handler (before it returns while waiting for async responses) is still called in proper sequence.
3. If any middleware calls `next(err)`, the first one to do it will be the only one that gets processed - others will be ignored.
4. The `req` object is shared among all the parallel middleware functions.  As such, you have to be aware of any race conditions in using it if you have async operations in your middleware writing to the `req` object.  It can certainly be used as a place to store independent properties (different for each middleware), but two parallel middlewares cannot be expecting sequential access to the same property (one sets it and the other reads what was set) because the execution order is unpredictable.  So, you are safest if each parallel middleware only reads standard properties and only writes its own properties.
5. Because the `req` object is shared, each middleware can't have its own value for `req.param` like normal middleware would.  As such, do not use `req.param` at all.  Instead, each parallel middleware is passed a fourth argument that is the `param` object.  This allows each parallel middleware to have its own param object.
6. If any middleware actually sends a response (as opposed to just setting up `req` variables for later route handlers), then you need to know that it's racy.  In general, I would not think you'd use parallel middleware to actually send a response, but I could imagine a few rare cases where you just want the first middleware that finds an answer to send the response.  If more than one attempts to send a response, you will get a warning about multiple responses (Express will catch it for you).  It is not blocked here.
7. It should go without saying that any async code in these parallel handlers finishes in an arbitrary order.  Do not execute handlers in parallel that require any specific ordering relative to each other.
8. Use of the `req.route` property in the parallel middleware is not supported.

---

**Minimal Testing So far**

I have not exhaustively tested this, but I do have it running in a sample app that just uses random timers to call `next()` in each of four parallel middlewares.  The route matching works.  The `params` feature works.  The middlewares do appear to run in parallel and complete in random order (per their random timers).

All parallel route handlers finish before subsequent routing continues.

The only state used during the parallel processing is stored either on the `req` object (which should be unique to each request) or in closures so it should be safe from race conditions of multiple parallel requests to the server that are in flight at the same time (though I haven't pounded on a server with lots of parallel requests to confirm that).

Comment: @최준호 - What do you think of this technique?  Does it work for you?